IntelliJ - Bring mvn clean install to a button
I am developing java maven projects using IntelliJ.
In order to compile the project with its dependencies, I use a lot mvn clean install
Every time, I end up clicking hte UI on this icon, then clicking on reload (please see screenshot)
I tried biding this action to a button on the keyboard or in the mouse.
However, I could not find which action is it.
The closest I could find was binding "Run Configuration", however, this does not take into account everything (all the steps from the screenshot)

Question:
How to bind mvn clean install to a button?

You can do this in Settings > Keymap. On the top left, you can search for "maven", then in the Keymap section, under Maven, you can "Choose a phase/goal to assign a shortcut".


This is what I was looking for. Thank you @Diego, accepted + upvoted
